# How to use Perl LibXML to add a ChildNode where one is missing?

Tags: xml, perl, xml-parsing, xml-libxml, child-nodes

I am using libXML to update a batch of XML settings files. Here is an example of the section of xml I am trying to update:

```xml
<Setting SID="2091">
  <Name>HME Cloud User Email</Name>
  <Value/>
</Setting>
```

I can properly update that section with the following code.

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl 

use File::Basename;
use XML::LibXML;
use XML::LibXML::XPathContext; 
 
@files = glob('C:\Users\1025144\Documents\timer_test\*.xml'); 

foreach $file (@files) 
{
    my $dom = XML::LibXML->load_xml(location => $file);
    my $xpc = XML::LibXML::XPathContext->new($dom);
    $xpc->registerNs('xsd',  'http://hme.com/Settings.xsd');
    
    #Add email 
    my($match9) = $xpc->findnodes('//xsd:Settings/xsd:Setting[@SID="2091"]/xsd:Value');
    $match9->removeChildNodes();
    $match9->appendText('email@email.com');
    
    open (OUTFILE, ">$file");               
    print OUTFILE $dom;
}

print "XML Files Updated."
```

but the issue is some of the settings files are missing the Value node for this SID, see example below:

```xml
<Setting SID="2091">
  <Name>HME Cloud User Email</Name>
</Setting>
```

I have been looking at the addChild to attempt to place the  node into this SID but I cant seem to figure out the syntax. I use perl off and on so I am hoping someone can help me figure out how to add this node or if there is an alternative solution that I can use if the SID has the Value node or not.

Any help is appreciated - Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use an `if`, if the Value doesn't exist, create it using `addNewChild`.

```
#! /usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;
use feature qw{ say };

use XML::LibXML;

my @files = @ARGV;

my $uri = 'http://hme.com/Settings.xsd';
for my $file (@files) {
    my $dom = 'XML::LibXML'->load_xml(location => $file);
    my $xpc = 'XML::LibXML::XPathContext'->new($dom);
    $xpc->registerNs('xsd',  $uri);

    if (my ($email) = $xpc->findnodes('//xsd:Settings/xsd:Setting[@SID="2091"]/xsd:Value')) {
        $email->removeChildNodes;
        $email->appendText('email@email.com');
    } else {
        my ($setting) = $xpc->findnodes('//xsd:Settings/xsd:Setting[@SID="2091"]');
        $setting->addNewChild($uri, 'Value')->appendText('email@email.com');
    }

    $dom->toFile("$file.new");
}

say "XML Files Updated."
```

*Notes:*

- Use [strict](http://p3rl.org/strict) and [warnings](http://p3rl.org/warnings).
- You don't need to [use](http://p3rl.org/use) [XML::LibXML::XPathContext](http://p3rl.org/XML::LibXML::XPathContext). Using [XML::LibXML](http://p3rl.org/XML::LibXML) is enough.
- Use `toFile` for printing XML.

Comment: That worked perfect! Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to worry about the node already existing if you delete it :)

```perl
my ( $setting ) = $xpc->findnodes( '//xsd:Settings/xsd:Setting[@SID="2091"]' )
   or die( "Setting not found\n" );

$_->unbindNode() for $xpc->findnodes( 'xsd:Value', $setting );

$setting->addNewChild( $uri, 'Value' )->appendText( 'email@email.com' );
```